# Can I use ProvisioningDeviceClient with a Pre-Generated SAS Token?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I would like to use `ProvisioningDeviceClient` on our device to access device provisioning service.
`ProvisioningDeviceClient` requires a `SecurityProvider` instance, but I see no `SecurityProvider` that allows me to specify a SAS token to use. There is `SecurityProviderSymmetricKey`, but this requires you to provide the PSK, and I presume it computes the SAS token for you based on the PSK.

However, in my application, I do not have access to the PSK -- I only have access to the SAS token. Our PSKs are in a secured area of the processor, and I can request it to generate a SAS token for me, but I cannot request the PSK.

How can I use `ProvisioningDeviceClient` with a pre-generated SAS token? It's like there should be a `SecurityProviderSASToken` class where you can specify the SAS token to use, but I don't think this class exists (yet).

Comment: What Azure IoT SDK language are you using?

Comment: I am using Azure IoT SDK for .NET, specifically in C#. https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp

Comment: You will need to use x509 and add to DPS the X.509 CA Public cert. See: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/tree/main/provisioning/Samples/device/X509Sample

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot use certificates. Our secure environment in our processor only allows us to store a key and then it generates SAS tokens. It does not have the ability to store certificates, so we must use symmetric keys. Is there no way to modify the Azure IoT SDK to add a security provider that uses a SAS token?

Comment: I am not sure about your environment. But did you also check TPM attestation - it looks to me you may be using it: [TPM attestation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/concepts-tpm-attestation) . Do you confirm?

Comment: I investigated TPM attestation, but we cannot use it for several technical reasons. I have looked through the SDK source code, and it appears there is no way to accomplish what I need to do with the SDK in its current form, so I am going to modify the SDK to work like I need it to.

Comment: Please leverage as well the issues section of the sdk for any troubles you find modifying the SDK. Have in mind the updates to SDK and retro-compatibility of your changes. I would add as answer to this the comment you did above.